# Distorted window panes (not all)

Tags: windows-10, distortion

I had to reset the Windows due to certain error (right clicking on any of the folders made File Explorer "Not responding", and trying to open any folder caused a green ribbon of infinite loading).

But after resetting, some of the program panes are distorted (such as Android Studio). Even on pressing Alt + Tab, the preview of the corresponding window shows the distortion.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: You should try updating your display adapter driver to the latest version offered by the manufacturer.